# Question on first-order inclusion probability.

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, sampling

> **Question:** Consider a finite population $~U=\{1,~2,~3\}~$ with 
>   $$p~\left(\{1,~2\}\right)=\dfrac 12~,~~~~p~\left(\{1,~3\}\right)=\dfrac 14~,~~~~p~\left(\{2,~3\}\right)=\dfrac 14~.$$
>   Then if $~\pi_k~$ denotes the first order inclusion probability of the $k^{\text{th}}$ unit, which of the following is **not** true ?
>
> $(1)~~\pi_1=\dfrac 34$
>
> $(2)~~\pi_2=\dfrac 34$
>
> $(3)~~\pi_1+\pi_2+\pi_3=1$
>
> $(4)~~\pi_1+\pi_2+\pi_3=2$

${}$

**My opinion:** We know that

> **First-order inclusion probability:** The first-order inclusion probability $π_i$ refers to the probability that unit $i$ is included in the sample.
>   $$π_i = Pr(i ∈ A) = \sum_{A; i∈A}P(A)$$

I came across [example$~(2.1)$](https://jkim.public.iastate.edu/teaching/book2.pdf) and found accordingly to their procedure

$$\pi_1=\dfrac 12+\dfrac 14=\dfrac 34~,~~\pi_2=\dfrac 12+\dfrac 14=\dfrac 34~,~~\pi_3=\dfrac 14+\dfrac 14=\dfrac 12$$ and hence $$~\pi_1+\pi_2+\pi_3=\dfrac 34+\dfrac 34+\dfrac 12=2~$$

Hence **option $\bf{(3)}$** is the correct answer here. But I am unable to understand how they did it (in which procedures they follow) ? Are they use some particular theorem or property ?

Please help to understand the fact.

Comment: Do you ask why $\pi_1=\frac12+\frac14$ and so on?

Comment: Exactly @NCh. I am a newcomer in this field. So I have no enough knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at definition: $$\pi_i = Pr(i \in A) = \sum_{A : i\in A} P(A)$$
The right hand side is a sum of $P(A)$ over all sets $A$ which containes $i$ as element.

Let us find $\pi_1$. Here $i=1$. Which sets contain $i=1$ as element? 
$1\in\{1,2\}$ and $1\in\{1, 3\}$. Sum up probabilities of these sets and get $$\pi_1=P(\{1,2\})+P(\{1,3\})=\frac12+\frac14=\frac34.$$

Comment: So according to you, It is noting but the definition of inclusion probability.

Comment: @nmasanta Of course, what else could it be if this is precisely the inclusion probability?